# Setup router with 1-1 NAT

Tags: router, ip-address, static-ip

How do you setup a router, or if possible the *Linksys WAG160Nv2* router to 1-1 NAT. I am asking this as i will like to give one of my LAN computers a Static "External" IP (which i've got from my ISP) so that it can be accesses outside the network.

> My connection type is RFC 2364 PPPoA
>
> My internet connection is ADSL+
>
> Multiplexing is VC DSL Modulation is in MultiPlex

However my ISP told me the following

> To use VCMUX encapsulation - which i
> cant seem to find anywhere in the
> router options
>
> And that the DNS is
> automatic

I read online that i should use bridged connection, but If i use other connection
type other than PPPoA / PPPoE i am not
able to use my login setting such as
user name and password. Will my
internet still work?

Thanks so much for any advise you can offer.

Comment: Do you want specific ports on your PC be accessible from the internet? Then maybe port forwarding is the option you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 (or more) external IP addresses?

Your internet router would keep the PPPoA/E settings, your second router would be set to bridge mode, which will use the first router for the internet thus not requiring any PPPoA/E details.

VC MUX is the encapsulating type, which you already have set fine if yours says Multiplexing (which is what vc mux is).

What situation are you using this setup in?  If you only have on external address, you don't need 2 routers.  If you want a specific server accessible from the internet, use port forwarding on your router to that specific server.

If you explain what you are doing a little more, we can offer more specific advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused as to exactly what you are asking, however the whole point of NAT is to basically give an ip address to a computer or device then share that ip to multiple computers / devices.

If you have multiple ips and want to assign one to a device, this process changes based on the router used and I have no experience using yours, but it typically involves turning NAT and DHCP off then assigning your public ips to the selected devices and machines.

Personally when I set something similar up, I ended up using two routers, one had NAT off and was simply used for the connection. I had 8 ips, one for the router itself (there is probably a better way than that, did it for ease) 3 assigned to one server, 3 to another server and one assigned to another router which provided NAT for the devices behind it.

I am out at the moment and it is very hard to type a detailed answer. If you want more information on anything I have written, let me know in comments and I will try to explain more/better when I get back.